# scss apply style to the last element

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to add `border-bottom` only to the last element. I have the following scss code:

```
.practiceTypeItem {
  &__container {
    border-top: 2px solid #E5E9F1;
  }
}

.practiceTypeItem:last-child {
  &__container {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #E5E9F1;
  }
}
```

However, it gets compiled to this css which of course is wrong. pseudo selector `last-child` has turned into class name.

```
.practiceTypeItem__container {
  border-top: 2px solid #E5E9F1;
}
.practiceTypeItem:last-child__container {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E5E9F1;
}
.luna-choice-list-item {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

and this is my html:

```
<ul>
  <li class="practiceTypeItem">
    <div class="practiceTypeItem__container">
      <label for="radio-foobar"><input type="radio" name="practiceTypeId" id="radio-1" value="1">Hello world</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="practiceTypeItem">
    <div class="practiceTypeItem__container">
      <label for="radio-foobar"><input type="radio" name="practiceTypeId" id="radio-1" value="1">Hello world</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="practiceTypeItem">
    <div class="practiceTypeItem__container">
      <label for="radio-foobar"><input type="radio" name="practiceTypeId" id="radio-1" value="1">Hello world</label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I appreciate any help or hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.practiceTypeItem {
  &__container {
    border-top: 2px solid #E5E9F1;
  }

  &:last-child &__container {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #E5E9F1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the parent element to a variable and reference that:

```
.practiceTypeItem {
    // This is the parent (.practiceTypeItem)
    $p : &;
    
    &__container {
        border-top: 2px solid #E5E9F1;
    }

    &:last-child {
        #{$p}__container {
            border-bottom: 2px solid #E5E9F1;
        }
    }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
.practiceTypeItem__container {
  border-top: 2px solid #E5E9F1;
}

.practiceTypeItem:last-child .practiceTypeItem__container {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E5E9F1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
.practiceTypeItem {
  &:last-child {
    &__container {
      border-bottom: 2px solid #E5E9F1;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what the OPs current code already does.